# Logistics in Kurukshetra war

Tags: mahabharata, war

How the communication,food,resting place,disposal of dead, etc managed in kurukshetra war with such a huge number of warriors?

Comment: Interesting question. Given the sheer amount of army divisions mentioned in the scriptures it must have been a difficult task!